# Import external module in a internal module?

Tags: typescript

So i'm building a library project in typescript for `Node.js`. I have to use at least one external reference --- `node.d.ts`.

I'm trying to use the `--out lib.js --declaration` feature from the compiler to generate the codes. However, without internal modules/namespaces, the `lib.js` file and its definitions are empty. Moreover, I want to keep a nice namespace when exported as a library.

For others use this library in ts, like

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/mylib/definitions.d.ts"/>
import mylib = require('mylib');
var A = mylib.A;
var AsubB = mylib.a.B;
```

Answer (score 0):

To able export your library with namespace you need use modules and to be accesible need export them.

Create a Module zoo on demo.ts file:

```
 module zoo {
        function open(): void{
            console.log("hello");
        };  
}

declare module "zoo"
{
    export = zoo;
}
```

Remember set compiler option:

```
tsc demo.ts --module commonjs
```

And usage:

```
  import x = require('zoo');
    x.open();
    // or
    zoo.open();
```

you can check this link should help more about typescript with nodejs:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/node/nodejs.html
and for use external modules https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html